# Передача данных из Adapter RecyclerView во Fragment

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

У меня есть Fragment, на котором находится RecyclerView.
Я уже использую один Listener, который передаю в конструктор Adapter, и который отвечает за нажатие на ItemView.

**Fragment**

```
private fun initViews(root : View){
        recordListAdapter = RecordListAdapter { viewModel.handleSelectedItem(it.id)
        }
        val divider = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)

        with(root.rv_record_list){
            adapter = recordListAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            addItemDecoration(divider)
        }
    }
```

Но на ItemView у меня находится еще несколько ImageButton, для которых я хочу сделать другие отдельные действия.

Неужели мне нужно передать все listener в adapter через конструктор, тем самым увеличивая его?

Может есть другие способы?

Видел способ передачи данные через Inteface, но они также объявляли его в Adapter, а потом инициализировали через adapter.

P.S. Да я могу напрямую в Adapter выполнять действия, но все же правильнее делать из Fragment?

В данный момент код выглядит так:

```
class RecordListAdapter (
    private val listener : (RecordItem) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordListAdapter.RecordListItemViewHolder>(){
    var items : List<RecordItem> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecordListItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_record_list, parent, false)
        return RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecordListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position], listener)
    }

    fun updateData(data : List<RecordItem>){
        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.Callback(){
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].id == data[newItemPosition].id


            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].hashCode() == data[newItemPosition].hashCode()

            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = items.size

            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = data.size
        }

        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        items = data
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    inner class RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(convertView),
        LayoutContainer {
        override val containerView: View?
            get() = itemView

        fun bind(record : RecordItem, listener: (RecordItem) -> Unit){
            Log.d("Item Recycler", record.id.toString())
            if(record.isSelected){
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                itemView.tv_name.textSize = 24f
            }
            else{
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(R.attr.colorTitle)
                itemView.tv_name.textSize = 14f
            }
            itemView.tv_name.text = record.name
            itemView.tv_duration.text = record.duration.millis.toStringTime()
            itemView.tv_date_created.text = record.createdDateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            itemView.btn_more.setOnClickListener{} // Хочу сделать другой Listener для кнопки 
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.invoke(record)   //listener для ItemView
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**. Adapter

```
class RecordListAdapter (
    private val listener : (RecordItem) -> Unit,
    private val onItemMoreListener: OnItemMoreListener
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordListAdapter.RecordListItemViewHolder>(){
    var items : List<RecordItem> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecordListItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_record_list, parent, false)
        return RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecordListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position], listener, onItemMoreListener)
    }

    fun updateData(data : List<RecordItem>){
        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.Callback(){
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].id == data[newItemPosition].id


            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].hashCode() == data[newItemPosition].hashCode()

            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = items.size

            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = data.size
        }

        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        items = data
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    inner class RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(convertView),
        LayoutContainer {
        override val containerView: View?
            get() = itemView

        fun bind(record : RecordItem, listener: (RecordItem) -> Unit, onItemMoreListener: OnItemMoreListener){
            Log.d("Item Recycler", record.id.toString())
            if(record.isSelected){
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                itemView.tv_name.textSize = 24f
            }
            else{
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(R.attr.colorTitle)
                itemView.tv_name.textSize = 14f
            }
            itemView.tv_name.text = record.name
            itemView.tv_duration.text = record.duration.millis.toStringTime()
            itemView.tv_date_created.text = record.createdDateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            itemView.btn_more.setOnClickListener{onItemMoreListener.onItemMoreClick(record)}
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.invoke(record)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemMoreListener{
        fun onItemMoreClick(record : RecordItem)
    }

}
```

**Fragment**

```
class RecordListFragment : BaseFragment(), RecordListAdapter.OnItemMoreListener{
         private fun initViews(root : View){
            recordListAdapter = RecordListAdapter { viewModel.handleSelectedItem(it.id),
        //Что передать?}
            val divider = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)

        with(root.rv_record_list){
            adapter = recordListAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            addItemDecoration(divider)
        }
    }

     override fun onItemMoreClick(record: RecordItem) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Нажали кнопку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вариант можно объявить интерфейс со всеми нужными вам методами и передавать соответственно только один аргумент. А так, в принципе, ничего особо страшного в обилии аргументов нет, если это требуется в рамках задачи.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можете помочь тогда мне. Я объявил интерфейс в Adapter, установил для кнопки Listener, также указал в параметрах конструктора.
Во Fragment имплементировал этот интерфейс и переопределил метод. Но что передать в конструктор в Fragment?

Comment: Наверное, вам нужно что-то типа такого: `recordListAdapter = RecordListAdapter( { viewModel.handleSelectedItem(it.id) }, this )`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, а не можете написать, что {} в данном случае делает? Показывает некоторое множество? поэтому нельзя использовать так recordListAdapter = RecordListAdapter( {viewModel.handleSelectedItem(it.id), this )

Comment: Не очень понимаю ваш вопрос. В `{}` находится лямбда. В вашем коде в комментарии она не закрыта и код некомпилируемый. У вас в этом проблема?